# What is the difference between char *name[10] and char (*name)[10]?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion

I am very confused about what the two notations denotes.
I know that the precedence of `()` is greater than `[]`, does that mean `char(*name)[10]` is a pointer and `char *name[10]` is an array?

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: Yes, with `char (*name)[10]` name is a pointer to arrays of 10 chars (`name = malloc(1000 * sizeof *name); strcpy(name[123], "foobar");`); with `char *name[10]` name is an array of 10 pointers to char (`name[4] = malloc(42);`).

Comment: oh I thought that char *name[10] is a pointer to the first element of the array "name" i.e. name[0].

Comment: `sizeof(char (*)[10] )` will be 10 times smaller than `sizeof(char *[10]) `

Comment: @NeerajKumar "thought that char *name[10] is a pointer" --> Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.  It as as you first queried: "char *name[10] is an array".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica please clear me one thing sir, when I type `char *a = "Hello"` and then use `printf("%s", a)` then it prints the whole string "Hello". So does that mean that `char *` is equivalent to `string` as in C++. If that is not, then please help me that how it is printing the whole "Hello" string.

Comment: @NeerajKumar In C++ the class std::string is not the same as a character array.  You may not use for example std::string s( "Hello" ); printf( "%s\n", s );; String literals are character arrays.

Comment: NeerajKumar, "does that mean that char * is equivalent to string as in C++" --> not equivalent although some similarity.  `a` is a pointer - an address - it is not the string.  It is a pointer to the beginning of a _string_.  `printf("%s", a)` receives that pointer and uses it to read and print the string's contents: the first character, then the next until `'\0'`.  Much like an house address in not a house, just a "pointer" to a house.  It does not inform where the house "ends", just where the house is located.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I got you!, it means `char *a ` is a starting point of an array of unknown size and when we use `printf("%s",a)` it will search until `'\0'` is found and prints the string. So why do we initialize a character array, I mean we can use `char *arr` instead of `char arr[10]`, as it is beneficial that the size is not defined and we can store as much as we want.

Comment: @NeerajKumar `char *arr` is the address to a "house" - some house - somewhere, not yet defined.  `char arr[10]` _is_ the house - its contents not yet defined.  Yes `char *arr` can point to any size string, yet the string is still not defined yet.  We initialize a character array to make the string.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica alright, It means that using `char *arr` for a string is not a good practice, we should use `char arr[10]`. Thanks for your help and giving your precious time to solve my issue :-)

Comment: @NeerajKumar With `char *arr`, `arr` is not a _string_.  It could point to one though.  Passing pointers around is good practice.  Yet the object needs to exist someplace.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ok one last doubt please, in `char *arr = "Hello"`, `arr` being a pointer is not accepting address rather taking a string. How is this possible as when I use `char *arr = 'Z'` it shows error and I have to use `char a = 'Z'` and then `char *arr = &a`. Does that mean that in `char *arr = "Hello"` the double quotes are doing two things, i.e. creating a null terminated string and second, providing the address of the first character to `arr`?

Comment: @NeerajKumar  `char *arr = "Hello"` --> Yes.  Note that  writing to  _string literal_  `"Hello"` should not be attempted.  [TTFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTFN).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225988/discussion-between-neeraj-kumar-and-chux-reinstate-monica).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This declaration

```
char *name[10];
```

declares an array of 10 elements of the type `char *`.

For example such an array can be initialized the following way

```
char *name[10] = { "Peter", "Tom", "Michael" };
```

All elements of the array that do not have a corresponding initializer will be implicitly initialized by `NULL`. That is the above declaration is equivalent to

```
char *name[10] = 
{ 
    "Peter", "Tom", "Michael", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL 
};
```

A pointer to the first element of the array will look like

```
char **p = name;
```

A pointer to the whole array will look like

```
char * ( *p )[10] = &name;
```

This declaration

```
char (*name)[10];
```

declares a pointer to object of the array type `char[10]`.

For example if you have an array declared like

```
char name_list[][10] =
{
    "Peter", "Tom", "Michael"
};
```

then you can declare a pointer to the first element of the array like

```
char (*name)[10] = name_list;
```

A pointer to the whole array can be declared like

```
char ( *p )[3][10] = &name_list;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    {
        char *name[10] = { "Peter", "Tom", "Michael" };

        char **p1 = name;
        puts( *p1 );
        
        char * ( *p2 )[10] = &name;
        puts( ( *p2 )[0] ); 
        // or 
        puts( **p2 );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    {
        char name_list[][10] =
        {
            "Peter", "Tom", "Michael"
        };
        
        char ( *p1 )[10] = name_list;
        puts( *p1 );
        
        char ( *p2 )[3][10] = &name_list;
        puts( ( *p2 )[0] ); 
        // or 
        puts( **p2 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Peter
Peter
Peter

Peter
Peter
Peter
```

Comment: Be aware that string literals are `const`. `const char *name[10] = { "Peter", "Tom", "Michael" };` would be more correct.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 In C, _string literals_ are not `const` even if code should not attempt to change them.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 In C string literals have types of non-constant character arrays though you may not change a string literal.

Answer (score 6):

`int *a[10]` - declares an array of 10 pointers to integer.

`int (*a)[10]` - declares a pointer to the array of 10 integers.

Comment: oh I thought that char *name[10] is a pointer to the first element of the array "name" i.e. name[0].

Answer (score 1):

> *name[10]

is an array **OF** 10 pointers. They are usually used when working with 2-dimensional arrays.

> (*name)[10]

This on the other hand is basically a pointer **TO** an array of 10 ints or whatever.